# SSH into Chromebook

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, chromebook

I'm attempting to SSH into a Chromebook in developer mode. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. installed and started ssh on port 2223 in the terminal. Confirmed by(copied by hand from the screen):

```
$ sudo systemctl status ssh
...
Active: active (running)...
...
Mar 29 ... Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2223
```

2. I've opened the port in the Chromebook settings: Developers -> Port Forwarding -> Add. It lists port 2223 open to (TCP)
3. It looks like it's open! When I nmap this computer from another it show that port open:

```
sudo nmap -p- 192.168.1.206
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-03-29 16:32 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.206
Host is up (0.010s latency).
Not shown: 65534 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2223/tcp open  rockwell-csp2
```

Finally, the error:

```
ssh csalem@192.168.1.206:2223
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.206:2223: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I keep checking the ip address because it seems like I'm missing something straitforward.

Comment: Can you SSH from the Chromebook into another device? You have to be running an SSH daemon into order to SSH into the Chromebook.

Comment: Does `ssh -p 2223 csapem@192.168.1.206` work? What OS and ssh software is your client running?

Comment: using the `-p` flag doesn't work. My client is MacOS, I'm assuming OpenSSH, though it was installed a while ago if it didn't come with the OS.

Comment: I'm not interested in ssh-ing from the chromebook, the chromebook is to be the server. The ssh server is running on the chromebook, as indicated in step 1. I'm not sure how that differs from a daemon

Comment: @Ramhound sshd might've done it. I was confusing the client and server. I'm still not connecting, but it's clear it's hit a host.